# Update from many rows to one without cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with a field that stores comma delimited values as a string. I would like to add more values to that string in one row from multiple rows in another table. Below you will see an example.

I had it in my head that COALESCE() would work, and I have an idea for how I could use that trick to load a variable, but I think that means I would have to use a cursor to gather all the values I want for each row of t1, and I would really like to avoid cursors. This table design is a mess that I inherited and I would rather avoid making it worse by using cursors everywhere to deal with it.

```
CREATE Table t1(
StringColumn VARCHAR(10)
)

CREATE Table T2(
    TestString VARCHAR(10),
    ConcatString VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO t1(StringColumn) VALUES('1,2,3')

INSERT INTO T2(TestString,ConcatString) VALUES('2','4')
INSERT INTO T2(TestString,ConcatString) VALUES('2','5')
INSERT INTO T2(TestString,ConcatString) VALUES('2','6')

INSERT INTO t1(StringColumn) VALUES('A,B,C')

INSERT INTO T2(TestString,ConcatString) VALUES('A','D')
INSERT INTO T2(TestString,ConcatString) VALUES('B','E')
INSERT INTO T2(TestString,ConcatString) VALUES('B','F')    

Begin Tran --Commit Rollback
UPDATE t1
Set t1.StringColumn = t1.StringColumn + ',' + t2.ConcatString
FROM t1 
INNER JOIN t2 ON charindex(t2.TestString,t1.StringColumn) <> 0

SELECT * FROM t1
```

Per this example the results are:

1,2,3,4

A,B,C,D

I would like the two rows of t1 to look like:

1,2,3,4,5,6

A,B,C,D,E,F

Thanks. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Storing comma separated values in a column is almost always the start of a headache for future queries and maintenance. It would be far better to design a schema that stores each value on a separate row.

Comment: Believe me I agree, but this is one of those cases that I'm sure is common where the data model has slowly grown in complexity over the last ten years or so. Now it's to the point where it works, but it's so complex that no manager is willing to accept the risk of rewriting it. The result is, as you point out, messes like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution will work if you want to stay away from cursors, loops, and are running at least SQL 2008. This actually ends up being more efficient (in SQL 2008+) than any function or cursor you could create.

You want to use some of the new XML features 2008 (or 2005?) introduced. Specifically, in your query, you want to construct an XML string using XML PATH mode. Once all of the results are jammed into a single XML String, you can construct a complex expression to return what you are after. Explained more in detail from msdn:

[MSDN Path Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189885%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Using the sample tables you provided, try this query:

```
SELECT
Test_String = T.StringColumn + (SELECT
                            (',' + t2.ConcatString)
                            FROM 
                                T1 t1
                            INNER JOIN T2 t2
                                ON charindex(t2.TestString,t1.StringColumn) <> 0
                            WHERE 
                            t1.StringColumn = t.StringColumn
                            FOR XML PATH( '' ))
FROM
    T1 T
```

Based on everything you said, it sounds like you may need to modify my query. You may need to do some additional joins, or perhaps change the guts of the query some. Let me know!

Comment: I modified this just slightly to the following and it did what I needed.

`Begin Tran --Commit rollback
UPDATE t1
set t1.StringColumn = T.StringColumn + (SELECT
                            (',' + t2.ConcatString)
                            FROM 
                                T1 t1
                            INNER JOIN T2 t2
                                ON charindex(t2.TestString,t1.StringColumn) <> 0
                            WHERE 
                            t1.StringColumn = t.StringColumn
                            FOR XML PATH( '' ))
FROM
    T1 T `

Thanks very much.

Comment: When I tried this in my actual database I had to add an ISNULL() wrapper around select to avoid making a constraint that checks for nulls angry. I'm not really sure why but it worked. If you have any ideas why this thing would ever want to insert a null into the field I would love to understand this statement better.

Comment: Without seeing the data, I can't say for sure. I guess it's possible that the where clause (where t1.StringColumn = t.StringColumn) doesn't always find a match. So maybe it was doing something like "t.stringcolumn + null". But like I said, I would need some data samples!

Comment: I think that explanation makes sense. I do know that there are rows for which the where condition won't find any matches.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use the row processing in here.
You can use a value table and then a while like this example:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(Id int identity,Value int)
DECLARE @MinId INT = (SELECT MIN(Id) FROM @T)
DECLARE @MaxId INT = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM @T)

DECLARE @ResultTable TABLE (Value int)

WHILE(@MinId <= @MaxId)
BEGIN
    INSERT @ResultTable
        SELECT Value
        FROM @T
        WHERE Id = @MinId

        SET @MinId += 1
END

SELECT *
FROM @ResultTable
```

I think this will help U ...

Comment: U can declare a variable and then have some if clauses and do what ever U want without any limitation. By the way the row processing is much faster than Cursor. :P